# How to set a background image on a custom javascript component?

Tags: javascript, css, custom-component

In the example, I have a native component with traditional HTML/CSS. I also have a Custom Component. In the native component, you can see that the `.anim-link` has a background image which works just fine. The exact same CSS is in the custom component as well. The animation is working as expected, but the background image isn't displaying at all.

**Why is the background image not displaying in the custom component?**

If you'd prefer to fork this **[Codepen](https://codepen.io/r3hab/pen/WNjpraQ)**, please do so.

```js
const template = document.createElement('template');
template.innerHTML = `
  <style>
    a {
      text-decoration: none;
      position: relative;
      color: #005fec;
    }

    a:before {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      border: solid 0px #005fec;
      top: 0px;
      bottom: 0px;
      left: 0px;
      right: 0px;
      opacity: 0;
      transition: all 0.3s;
      transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
      border-radius: 4px;
      filter: blur(4px);
    }

    *:focus {
      outline: none;
    }

    a:focus-visible:before {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      border: solid 2px #005fec;
      top: -8px;
      bottom: -8px;
      left: -8px;
      right: -8px;
      opacity: 1;
      filter: blur(0px);
    }

    a:focus-visible:before {
      left: -4px;
      right: -4px;
    }

    .anim-link {
      display: inline-flex;
      position: relative;
      color: #005fec;
      font-size: 1.25rem;
      align-items: center;
    }
    .anim-link span {
      background: url("https://nextivaweb.imgix.net/icons/Arrow-Right-Hover-Animation.svg") no-repeat center;
      content: "";
      height: 15px;
      width: 15px;
      position: absolute;
      right: -20px;
    }

    .anim-link::after {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      transform: scaleX(0);
      height: 1px;
      bottom: -5px;
      left: 0;
      background-color: #005fec;
      transform-origin: bottom right;
      transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
    }

    .anim-link:hover::after {
      transform: scaleX(1);
      transform-origin: bottom left;
    }
  </style>
  <a href="" class="anim-link"><slot></slot><span></span></a>
`;

class CustomAnimLink extends HTMLElement {

  static get observedAttributes() {
    return ['name', 'destination'];
  }

  constructor() {
    super();

    this.showInfo = true;
    this.attachShadow({
      mode: 'open'
    });
    this.shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
  }

  get anchor() {
    return this.shadowRoot.querySelector('a');
  }

  get name() {
    return this.getAttribute('name');
  }

  set name(value) {
    if ('string' === typeof value) {
      this.setAttribute('name', value);
    }
  }

  get destination() {
    return this.getAttribute('destination');
  }

  set destination(value) {
    if ('string' === typeof value) {
      this.setAttribute('destination', value);
    }
  }

  attributeChangedCallback(attrName, oldValue, newValue) {
    switch (attrName) {
      case 'destination':
        this.anchor.href = newValue;
        break;
      case 'name':
        this.anchor.textContent = newValue;
        break;
    }
  }
}

window.customElements.define('custom-anim-link', CustomAnimLink);
```

```css
/* Roboto Font */
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,100i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,700,700i,900,900i&display=swap");
/*resets*/
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html, body {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.container {
  padding: 10px;
}

hr {
  margin: 2rem 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  color: #005fec;
}

a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border: solid 0px #005fec;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  border-radius: 4px;
  filter: blur(4px);
}

*:focus {
  outline: none;
}

a:focus-visible:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border: solid 2px #005fec;
  top: -8px;
  bottom: -8px;
  left: -8px;
  right: -8px;
  opacity: 1;
  filter: blur(0px);
}

a:focus-visible:before {
  left: -4px;
  right: -4px;
}

.anim-link {
  display: inline-flex;
  position: relative;
  color: #005fec;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  align-items: center;
}
.anim-link span {
  background: url("https://nextivaweb.imgix.net/icons/Arrow-Right-Hover-Animation.svg") no-repeat center;
  content: "";
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -20px;
}

.anim-link::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  height: 1px;
  bottom: -5px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #005fec;
  transform-origin: bottom right;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.anim-link:hover::after {
  transform: scaleX(1);
  transform-origin: bottom left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Native Component</h1>
  <a href="#" class="anim-link">See all-in-one <span></span></a>  
  <hr>
  <h1>Custom Component</h1>
  <custom-anim-link name="See all-in-one" destination="#"></custom-anim-link>  
</div>
```

Comment: do you need to define the css inside the template ?

Comment: Yes. It's part of the 'Shadow DOM', and it's encapsulated CSS, which means it doesn't leak out and nothing leaks in. This is the way they're designed. If I try to reference the CSS from a traditional stylesheet (i.e.; `<link rel="stylesheet" href="...">`), it wouldn't work.

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but it's not a problem of the background. The `span` inside the component is missing in the DOM. I couldn't tell you why.